# Unable to call a base module from an extended module using Application in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Hi I am trying to call a base module from an app file using an extended module inbetween.

Base Module: Basemodule.js

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
exports.baseModmessage1=function()
{
console.log('Module1:base Module: Message 1')
}
exports.baseModmessage2=function()
{
console.log('Module1:base module: Message 2')    
}
```

Extended Module: Extendedmodule.js

```
var baseModule = require ('./Basemodule.js');

exports.extendedModule = function()
{
    console.log ("This came from extended module function");

    function moreMessage()
    {
        var baseMessage = baseModule
        baseMessage.baseModmessage1();
    }
}
```

The application: app.js

```
var mainCall = require('./Extendedmodule.js');

mainCall.extendedModule();

mainCall.extendedModule.moreMessage();
```

All files are in the same local folder. I am able to get the extended module message but there seems to be a problem when calling the base module.

```
C:\wks\guru99\L2_extendingmodules>node app.js

This came from extended module function

C:\wks\guru99\L2_extendingmodules\app.js:5
mainCall.extendedModule.moreMessage();
                        ^

TypeError: mainCall.extendedModule.moreMessage is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wks\guru99\L2_extendingmodules\app.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moreMessage` is declared inside the body of `extendedModule`; it's not a property of the `extendedModule` function being exported and therefore can't be accessed in the way you're attempting to.

either export `moreMessage` directly, or define it outside of the body of your `extendedModule` function then attach it to `extendedModule`:

> extendedModule.moreMessage = function () { /* ... */ };

Comment: Hi, I exported moreMessage directly and it worked. Can you teach me how to define it outside of the body and attach to extendeModule so that it works. Thanks in advance.